# How to get the Ip address in PHP when calling through cron job?

Tags: php

I am running a php page where I have set a variable with IP address and running that page through cron jobs to update a table column. Since the application is running through cron jobs, it will not hit the browser and that is why I think I am not getting the Ip address. I am getting the IP address as null. Can anyone help?

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
mysqli_query($con, "update table set colum='".$ip."' where id=1");
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to re-examine what you're trying to accomplish here. If you're running this script via cron jobs, there's no web request coming in from a user/client, so you won't have an IP address. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Yes exactly. You are right. I have changed my code and ommited cron job.

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee so what are you trying to achieve now?

Comment: There's no way you can get right answers if you don't explain your ultimate goal. Scheduling a command-line script to log the IP address of the remote host that doesn't exist does not make any sense. Please edit the question and explain what you're trying to accomplish rather than _how_ you're trying to do it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To get the IP address in PHP when running a script through a cron job, you can use the `$_SERVER` superglobal variable. This variable contains an array of information about the server and the current script, including the IP address of the client that made the request.

To get the client's IP address, you can use the following code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

This will retrieve the client's IP address and store it in the `$ip` variable.

If you are running the script through a cron job, the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable will not be set, as the script is not being accessed through a browser. In this case, you can use the `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` variable to get the server's IP address instead:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

This will retrieve the IP address of the server that the script is running on.

You can then use the `$ip` variable in your script as needed, for example to update a table column in your database.

Comment: Unsure how this answers OP's question, as the question is unclear at this point. Also your first paragraph contradicts your second paragraph...

Comment: As already said, half of the question doesn't make any sense. What's the client in a command-line script? How can there be an IP address when there is no networking involved? The only possible answer is "no network = no IP".